# FreeCADCmd export calculation

Tags: python, export, freecad

my goal ist to calculate the volume of a solid from a STEP file. Within the python console inside the FreeCAD GUI it is no problem. But I need to do it on the command line with a python script. The problem is, how can I export my result???

I tried to figure out how to export a simple text or whatever from a python script run by FreeCADCmd for a while now. I found no way to export anything ... A simple print("Hello world") doesn't work. Also writing a file doesn't work. The log file is clean, just saying executed test.py-.

I hope anyone can help me on this!!!

Thanks,
Andi

Comment: Hi, you may run a FreeCAD in any py file.  Then you're free to do anything you might do within python scripts

Comment: Helpus to help you, include your code in your question.